# Help With MultiCD

Tags: linux-mint, iso

This is where I'm stuck at. If you know what to do now will you let me know?

```
TAPITSFIMM-maya multicd # chmod +x multicd.sh
TAPITSFIMM-maya multicd # ./multicd.sh
multicd.sh 7.1
Extracting ISO images with mount; will build multicd.iso; UID 0.

AntiX
Austrumi
Caine
Feather
Finnix
Fusion Linux
GParted Live
Parted Magic
emtest86+

Continuing in 2 seconds - press Ctrl+C to cancel
Copying files for each plugin...
Copying AntiX...
cp: reading `/home/jahaic/multicd/temporary-mountpoints/antix/antiX/linuxfs': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend `/home/jahaic/multicd/multicd-working/antiX/linuxfs': Input/output error
cp: reading `/home/jahaic/multicd/temporary-mountpoints/antix/antiX/linuxfs.md5': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend `/home/jahaic/multicd/multicd-working/antiX/linuxfs.md5': Input/output error
cp: reading `/home/jahaic/multicd/temporary-mountpoints/antix/antiX/vmlinuz': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend `/home/jahaic/multicd/multicd-working/antiX/vmlinuz': Input/output error
TAPITSFIMM-maya multicd #
```

Comment: can you post what you get in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with MultiCD itself,but it looks like either your hard drive is failing or the files are corrupt somehow.

Reboot into a LiveCD and run `fsck` on your main partition, probably something like /dev/sda1.  You can check by running `df` and looking for where "/" is mounted.  In the LiveCD run `fsck /dev/sda1` and you'll probably find some sort of error.

I recently had an error with `cp: failed to extend` and something was wrong with the files themselves.  Try to find a checksum from where you downloaded MultiCD or the files you're using with it.  Maybe just try redownloading.

Good luck.

**EDIT:** I said I had a similar problem because of a corrupt file, and that's what I thought at the time.  I later learned it really was a dying hard drive.  So chances are pretty high that your hard drive might be failing.